# NetBeans 8.2 WHERE can i find it?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I want to use NetBeans for Java Projects but i can't find it.
The new update on Apache.org only has NetBeans 14... I'm thinking there is no more available ):

I'm on linux btw.

Comment: "_Apache.org only has NetBeans 14_" - you can find all the versions from the most recent (14) back to v9.0 in the [archive section](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/archive/index.html) of that site. But... as for NetBeans 8, I believe Oracle no longer provides its old Java+NetBeans8 downloads. I have to ask: **Why would you need that, anyway?** If you provide more details, maybe there is a way to do what you need using a later version.

Comment: I haven't tried it, and be wary, but it looks like you can still download NetBeans 8.2 from https://netbeans-ide.informer.com/download/

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the pre-Apache versions of NetBeans seem to no longer be available.

As a former NetBeans user, I happen to have the installation script for NetBeans 8.2 on my drive. I've [uploaded it](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1D4aKv5hTplr5XrmORuXfm6_MOdaM7vdn?usp=sharing) to Google Drive if you absolutely need it. Have fun :)

Otherwise, the latest and greatest should be fine and I can't see no reason for not using it.

Comment: Man appreciate it FR, I know the latest version is great but i wanna feel the old days with 8.2 HAHA, TY so much man!

Comment: Do you have the MAC version for NetBeans 8.2, I have tried from https://netbeans-ide.informer.com/download/ but it is not working for me.

Comment: No, I don't have the MacOS version.

Answer (score 1):

The old Netbeans 8.2 can be downloaded from
https://archive.org/download/jdk-8u111-nb-8_2